# $( \ X\to G \ , \ \star \ )$ is a group if $(\varphi \star \psi)(a) = \varphi(a) \star \psi(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

> Let $X$ be a set and $G$ a group with the operation $\star$. Show that the set
> $$
> \mathcal{X} = \Big\{ \varphi : X\to G \mid \text{$\varphi$ is a function} \Big\}
> $$
> is a group with the operation
> \begin{equation}\label{star}
> \big(\varphi \star \psi\big)(a) \; = \; \varphi(a) \star \psi(a)  \qquad \quad \forall\,a\in G.
> \end{equation}

So associative is pretty easy since $(G,\star)$ is a group:
Let $\varphi,\tau,\phi\in\mathcal{X}$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
        ((\varphi\star\tau)\star\phi)(g) &= (\varphi\star\tau)(g)\star\phi(g)\\
        &= (\varphi(g)\star\tau(g))\star\phi(g)\\
        &=\varphi(g)\star (\tau(g)\star\phi(g))&G \text{ group}\\
        &= \varphi(g)\star(\tau\star\phi)(g)\\
        &= (\varphi\star(\tau\star\phi))(g)
    \end{align*}
And for identity, let $id:G\to G$ with the map $g\mapsto e$, with $e$ the identity on G, is a function and acts as an identity for $\mathcal{X}$:
$$(\varphi\star id)(g) = \varphi(g)\star id(g) = \varphi(g)\star e = \varphi(g) = e\star \varphi(g) = id(g)\star\varphi(g) = (id\star\varphi)(g).$$

But I'm having trouble proving closure and inverses. Since we don't know if an element is bijective or not, then we can't construct an inverse. And for closure, how can I show that $\varphi(a) \star \psi(a)$ is still a function?

Comment: Do you mean $\phi: X\to G?$ If not, what role does $X$ play here?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, you are right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that the free abelian group is a group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439798/show-that-the-free-abelian-group-is-a-group)

Comment: @fitzcarraldo That is essentially a duplicate. I wonder if this is a recent assignment.

Comment: To get the right spacing, use "`:`" not "`\colon`" , and "`\mid`" not "`|`". And frankly, it doesn't make sense to say "φ is a function" because (X→G) **is** the set of functions from X to G...

Comment: Nitpick: it might be confusing to use the same graphic symbol ("$\star$") for both operations. Rather, perhaps it's better to let them both blank, being meant that the due one is there according to the context.

Comment: @user21820: Actually, `\colon` provides good spacing for function definitions... at least to my taste...

Comment: It might be worth trying to prove that this group is isomorphic to the direct product of $|X|$ copies of $G$, $\prod_{x\in X}G$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Well... I don't agree because "f : S→T" actually means "f ∈ S→T", so it's supposed to be a relation-symbol. =)

Comment: @user21820: I do not follow your "actually means"; never encountered such a claim before. Not sayiing it's false, just saying I've never seen it before. I don't consider the colon in functional notation a relational symbol: to me it's punctuation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: It is not commonly taught, but it is in fact standard when you view "f : S→T" as a *typing* claim, because it is standard to use "x : S" to mean "x has type S". This is especially crystallized in the typing rule (  x : S  ;  f : S→T  ⊢  f(x) : T  ).

Comment: @user21820: Fair enough: if you think it's relational, you use `:`; if you want it treated as punctuation, you use `\colon`. This is exactly what Knuth says in *The $\TeX$book*, in fact: page 134, "If you want the `:` character to be treated as a punctuation mark instead of as a relation, just call it ``\colon`:` `$f:A\to B$` $f:A\to B$; `$f\colon A\to B$` $f\colon A\to B$."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint. When the group operation is function composition a function must be a bijection to have an inverse. But that's not the group operation that matters here. To invert $f$ you have to find a function $g$ that inverts the values of $f$ as they occur.

If you stare at your last sentence you might see that you are actually describing the function that's the product of the two you started with.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually work out what an inverse looks like quite explicitly. Take an arbitary $\varphi \in \mathcal X$. The question is, can we construct a function (let's denote it, completely coincidentally, as $\varphi^{-1}: X \to G$) which satisfies $$\varphi \star \varphi^{-1} \equiv \operatorname{id}.$$

I claim that you can define $\varphi^{-1}$ as
$$\varphi^{-1}(a) = \varphi(a)^{-1} \quad \forall a \in X$$
Note that this is well-defined: $g \equiv \varphi(a) \in G$ so it has an inverse $g^{-1}$.

I will leave it as an exercise for you to prove this claim.

Answer (score 2):

Your set is $G^X$ and it is a group isomorphic to the product of $|X|$ copies of $G$.

Comment: This only makes sense if $ X $ is finite without a bit of work to define $ |X| $, normally Cartesian products of groups are only done in introductory lectures for finitely many multiplicands.